# text-align justify like in word

Tags: html, css

How can I cast paragraphs with `text-align: justify;` and line breaks in text over the full line width?

HTML default is to align lines with a line-break to left. 
I like to cast it out over the full line width, like it is in word and other typographic software.

To avoid miss understanding, clarifying typographic soft and hard wraps:

soft wrap: line break 
hard wrap: paragraph break / and and start of a new paragraph

Justify casting word

[image: Text cast justify in word]

Justify casting web browser

[image: justify casting web browser]

```html
<p style="text-align: justify; font-family: Arial, Lora, Open Sans;">This text has text-align: justify; in the web browser as you can see in this paragraph. Now soft wraps follow.<br>
    This is a test<br>
    to show how text<br>
    is cast in word<br>
    And the text is aligned to left in stead of casting it to 100% width.</p>
```

Comment: Can you show your markup? I think the behavior is expected, and what you're seeing in your web browser is actually hard wraps (are you breaking lines using `<br>`?). Soft wraps are automatically performed by the layout engine, and should fully justify texts when it happens. Hard wraps, on the other hand, will not be casted to full width. Then again, I can't really diagnose your issue unless you share the markup.

Comment: @Terry I'm using <br> as soft line wraps. I expect <br> to be a the equivalent to a typographic soft wrap and a paragraph end </p> the equivalent to a typograpic hard wrap.

Comment: Check your font name also, because some fonts are not supports such formatting, try with common font family like "Arial".

Comment: font should not matter as of my knowledge. Neither works with Arial, Open Sans nor Lora

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just not supported. Even the [`text-justify`](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-justify) property seems to lack such format.

Comment: Any kind of breaks, such as `<p>`s and `<br>`s are interpreted as hard wraps (soft wraps are inserted automatically by the layout engine, and cannot be user-defined), so the text on the orphaned line will not be justified. That is part of the specification.

Answer (score 3):

I think problem is that your text is not separated by line as it does in MS Word.

**Note** Keep in mind that you can't justify single line in CSS. To fix that use *hack* with `:after` element:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

p:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  This is text
  </p>
  <p>
  to show how text
  </p>
  <p>
  is cast in word
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for unclear question. I know your solution, however this only works for multiple paragraphs. I'n my case I do actually have line breaks in the sense of typographic soft-wraps, not paragraph wraps. See edited questions.